# How to show google plus profile picture on navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, google-plus-signin

The below code is from github to log in via gmail in android app.I did some modification to show profile picture using volley.
Its working fine.
I just want to shows these things in navigation drawer.

Profile picture,name and email id.

I used the navigation drawer activity present in android studio.
I just tried to send these things using bundle to send to another activity but failed.

```
        Drawable drawable=profilePhoto.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        Intent intent3=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent3.putExtra("picture", b);
        startActivity(intent3);
```

and on receiving side

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0,100);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePhoto);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**Any help will be great**

```
         public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView,textViewEmail;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlesingin);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
   profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);


    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]

    // [START customize_button]
    // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
    // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
    // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
    // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
    // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
    // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
    // difference.
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // [END customize_button]
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));

        textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        //Loading image
        profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]

// [START signOut]
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END signOut]

// [START revokeAccess]
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END revokeAccess]

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
        case R.id.disconnect_button:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}

public void skip(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Send the url of the profile icon to the drawer activity or store it in sharedpreferences and retrieve it and use a image loader to display image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with ***"a person"*** about using [Piccaso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

You can refer to my following code using Piccaso:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            // Views inside NavigationView's header
            mUserTextView.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
            mEmailTextView.setText(acct.getEmail());
            Uri uri = acct.getPhotoUrl();
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(uri)
                    .placeholder(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                    .error(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                    .into(mProfileImageView);
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
```

More details, please refer to [my sample project at GitHub](https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo). Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad it could help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Glide or Picasso to load the image URL, rather than passing a Bitmap around. If you do want the Bitmap locally, then you could write to disk and pass the image's URI to the next Activity, instead of passing a Bitmap.

So at this point:

```
Drawable drawable=profilePhoto.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

..after creating the byte[], you could write it to disk, then pass the URI to the next Activity. This would require a permission in your manifest if you aren't already using it.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

http://square.github.io/picasso/