# How to Integrate Google+ id,profile name and Profile picture to Sliding Menu from already Signed In Google+ account

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-plus, google-signin

My Problem is i want to Integrate My Google+ id,name and Profile picture and sign out Button with Sliding Menu(Navigation Drawer)

As My google+ Signin is Successfull and for Sliding Menu i am refer to androidhive.info Website [enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Here is My MainActivity.java(i.e Google signinActivity)

```
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


 import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]

    // [START customize_button]
    // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    // [END customize_button]
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {


    }
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }

// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

        //GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
       // mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
       // updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Tab.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);

  // Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
  // startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]

// [START signOut]
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END signOut]

// [START revokeAccess]
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END revokeAccess]

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {

       // findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
        case R.id.disconnect_button:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

and i am jumping to Main_TAb(slinding MenuActivity)

Here is code for Main_Tab

Main_TAb.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.MoviesFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.NotificationsFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.PhotosFragment;
 import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.SettingsFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.other.CircleTransform;

  public class Main_Tab extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

// urls to load navigation header background image
// and profile image
private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
    txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in GMail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Clear All'
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// show or hide the fab
private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
    }
 }
```

Please try post your Answer to My code by copypasting for more understanding as I am a begainner to android development

Comment: Pls try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653645/how-to-show-google-plus-profile-picture-on-navigation-drawer

Comment: @-BNK  i know how to call the id and Profile pic  in Sign in Activity but i dont know how to Call it on Sliding Menu( navigation drawer) the Link you provided is not Sufficient and also confusing to solve my Problem Please help Me more in detail